# Ferris wheel bars

Tags: design

I am trying to build the High Roller ferris wheel at the Linq in Las Vegas. I want to sink a bar through two 2x2 domes. Can I do that with two of these parts? Is there a way to sink a single bar through 2 domes and 1 transparent 2x2 round brick?

[2x2 dome top hollow stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=553c&name=Brick,%20Round%202%20x%202%20Dome%20Top%20-%20Hollow%20Stud%20with%20Bottom%20Axle%20Holder%20x%20Shape%20%20%20Orientation&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=S&C=12&O=%7B%22color%22:%2212%22,%22st%22:%224%22,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22100%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you cannot pass a bar through dome version you are interested in (actually any of the versions of this dome as they all are blocked one way or another) as seen in this picture from [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/parts/30367c/brick-round-2-x-2-dome-top-hollow-stud-with-bottom-axle-holder-x-shape-orientation/):

[image]

However, you may consider [Brick, Round 2 x 2 Dome Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15395#T=C) which does have an option to attach bar through it.

[image]